# join table on Cascaded model not updated

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entity classes (Class A and Class B) mapped to database tables. They are cascaded so that saving object of class A would reflect change in table concerned with Class B as well. Now I want to have a join table with primary key from Class B and primary key of new entity Class (Class C). I used standard hibernate @JoinTable annotation. But Join Table is not updated. Am I allowed to do so in hibernate?

Class A(Fieldvisit)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fieldVisitId")
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,CascadeType.DELETE})
private Collection<Fieldvisitdetail> fieldvisitdetailCollection;
```

Class B(Fieldvisitdetail)

```
    @JoinTable(name = "fieldvisitgeo",
        joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "fieldVisitDetailId", referencedColumnName = "fieldVisitDetailId")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "geoId", referencedColumnName = "geoId")})    
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "fieldvisitdetailCollection", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Geo> geoId=new HashSet<Geo>();
```

Class C (Geo)

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Fieldvisitdetail> fieldvisitdetailCollection= new HashSet<Fieldvisitdetail>();
```

Code for Saving to database

```
    public void addFieldVisit(Fieldvisit visitReportInfo){        
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(visitReportInfo);
    }
```

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: @kostja I've added the code. Will you please have alook at it.